# Different navbar ordering for different devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I would like to have a reverse ordering for my navbar in mobile devices. I have defined 2 `div`s for this purpose: one for xs devices and one for small-up devices. However, the current code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-my-collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>

<!-- sm-up devices devices -->                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-my-collapse hidden-sm-up">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="hidden">
                            <a href="#page-top"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Item1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Item2</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

<!-- xs devices -->                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse hidden-xs">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="hidden">
                            <a href="#page-top"></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Item2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Item1</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
```

At the moment, it works for xs devices, but for other sizes, I see both navbars!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all `collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right` classes. 
Also include all `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl` classes to your `navbar-my-collapse` div to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

On the sm-collapse, you need the class `.hidden-xs`, while on the xs-collapse you need the class `.visible-xs-block`.

This way, the sm-collapse will be hidden on xs devices, while the xs-collapse will only render on xs devices.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, but I don't think so.. It got even worse. Now both of them are visible on xs devices, plus they are still both visible on small-up devices

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism Hmm, that's strange. Can I see a portion of the current code? Did you include the meta tag for mobile viewports? Also, have a look at the documentation on http://getbootstrap.com/css.

Comment: I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. I tried the `navbar-my-collapse` div with `hiddem-sm hidden-md hidden-lg`. It is still visible on small-up devices!

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism What does the `.navbar-custom`, `.navbar-my-collapse` and `.navbar-main-collapse` say?

Comment: Nothing except colors. `navbar-main-collapse` works as expected. The problem is with the `hidden-sm` that does not work.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism Can you update the code sample to what you currently have? Give me a few minutes and I'll show you how to write it. (Not at home rn)

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism Glad to hear that!